# Why do I get different distro versions?

Tags: 14.04

```
~$ uname -a

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:45:15 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Are they differ in something I mean command outputs or what? I didn't do anything wrong as I recall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uname -` get name and information about current kernel

```
lsb_release --
```

print distribution specific information

The lsb_release command prints certain LSB (Linux Standard Base) and Distribution information.

<sup>Source:Man Pages</sup>

Comment: mm, I get it now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is only one release 14.04. You have the kernel that is used in an update. These updates are there so that someone who installs Ubuntu now, does not have to completely reinstall all the packages in LTS release.

No matter how you install you will end up with what you have now.

Comment: but when I run `apt-cache policy linux-generic` I get `Installed: (none) Candidate: 3.13.0.46.53`