# Point Release upgrade from 14.04.1 to 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade to 14.04.2 point release from 14.04.  What I did was:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade &&  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then I wanted to upgrade to 3.16 kernel, since it wasn't done with the the above command, so what I did was:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-utopic
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic
```

Now when I do:

`uname -a` I get

`Linux Y500 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION= I get

VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

And when I do `lsb_release -a` I get

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I know that `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` both refer to different info, but why does 
`cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=` show different version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** That series of HWE kernels actually came out before the 14.04.2 point release.

The real question here is, why does `uname -v` output `#44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015` on Ubuntu *14.04.**2***? That is, why does a 14.04.2 system receive [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernels whose build numbers are tagged 14.04.1?

Here's why your question boils down to that specific point:

- `lsb_release -a` and `cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=` agree; they both say you have 14.04.2 (which you do). Therefore the only apparent discrepancy is between information given by `uname` about your kernel and information in both `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/os-release` about your system as a whole.
- You ran `uname -a`, not `uname -v`. But `uname -a` prints all available information ever printed by `uname` (it is equivalent to `uname -snrvmpio`, when `-i` and `-o` are known). The output you're interested in is confined to the field confusingly called "the kernel version" in [`man uname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/uname.1.html).
- Although it's sometimes called the "kernel version," it's really better to think of it as a build number--or build identifier, if you don't like calling non-numeric strings "numbers." The output of `uname -v` changes to enable users [to distinguish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124466/what-is-the-difference-of-kernel-distributions-release-and-version) kernels built as separate releases in a series, even if they are of the same underlying "kernel release" (`uname -r`).

The first step in understanding why your "kernel version" contains 14.04.1 and not 14.04.2 is to note that most kernel version strings, including for downstream Ubuntu kernels, don't contain *any* version information about the operating system as a whole. For example, on my 15.04 system:

```
ek@Io:~$ uname -v
#12-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 3 04:03:26 UTC 2015
```

This is the more common situation. The first word (`#12-Ubuntu`) indicates this is the twelfth downstream Ubuntu build of this particular kernel--or, in any case, that it is the twelfth in a series of builds, which may or may not consist entirely of kernels with the same `uname -r`.

An HWE kernel in Ubuntu contains numbers indicating a particular release of Ubuntu because it is backported from a later Ubuntu release and should be readily distinguishable from *that* Ubuntu release's builds. To distinguish HWE builds of Linux 3.16 provided through [linux-generic-lts-utopic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-generic-lts-utopic) [image: Install linux-generic-lts-utopic] for [Trusty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) from those provided through [linux-generic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-generic) [image: Install linux-generic] for [Utopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.10_.28Utopic_Unicorn.29), the Trusty builds contain 14.04.1 in the kernel version string.

Why not 14.04.2 instead of 14.04.1? (After all, the [14.04.2 release notes](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-February/000192.html) say "this point release contains an updated kernel and X stack..." The [14.04.1 release notes](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-July/000188.html) say no such thing.)

The reason is that [linux-generic-lts-utopic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-generic-lts-utopic) [image: Install linux-generic-lts-utopic]--and the first of the packages it [pulled in as dependencies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) to actually install a 3.16 kernel--was released for and installable on Trusty *between* the 14.04.1 and 14.04.2 point releases.

To check this, you can visit [Ubuntu on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu) and [search for the `linux-generic-lts-utopic` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=linux-generic-lts-utopic), revealing [`linux-meta-lts-utopic`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-utopic) as the underlying source package. Then clicking on ["View full publishing information"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-utopic/+publishinghistory) or ["View full change log"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-utopic/+changelog) reveals the history of the package.

In particular, [in the publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-utopic/+publishinghistory), note:

- All entires list [Trusty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/linux-meta-lts-utopic) as the target, so this pertains to your system; we are not looking at packages for the wrong Ubuntu release.
- The first packages considered stable, i.e., rolled out to users in the *updates* or *security* pockets (rather than just the *proposed* pocket) begin with [3.16.0.25.19](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-utopic/3.16.0.25.19) on *2014-12-11 01:25:33 UTC*.

That is, `linux-meta-lts-utopic` came out for Trusty on December 11, 2014, which was [ten weeks before](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=February%2020%2C%202015%20-%20December%2011%2C%202014) the [14.04.2 point release on February 20, 2015](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-February/000192.html). When these kernels came out, they were built for and tested on 14.04.1 systems, not 14.04.2 systems, so their builds were (and should thus probably remain, for consistency) numbered with the pattern `#N~14.04.1-Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

**Mitch** that's basically the same question that I asked you [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592632/why-do-i-get-different-distro-versions) before :) I also tried to figure it out.

I tried googling and visiting different forums including Ubuntu official sources and in conclusion this what we get:

Ubuntu 14.04.2 ships with default Utopic kernel and it is 3.16.0.30 (stable) e.g. from `apt-cache policy` I get kernel:

```
Installed: 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1

linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic:
  Installed: 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1
  Candidate: 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1

linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic:
  Installed: 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1
  Candidate: 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1
```

And what I did I downloaded and reinstalled Ubuntu using official image from ubuntu.com when I tried to upgrade it the way you did I got the same kernel as you are now. I think that's because it installes the latest Utopic kernel but not the stable one for Trusty Tahr, because I still get 3.16.0.30 kernel version.