# Update from 14.04.2 to 14.04.3 not happening

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have Ubuntu version 14.04.2 installed and want to upgrade to 14.04.3 (Kernel 3.19 has few fixes for me)

When I do

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

I get

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

But I still have 3.16 Kernel, I never got any message about upgrade and when I do

```
do-release-upgrade
```

(either with -d or -p) I get

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I tried to reboot, for the case that I missed the upgrade, but nothing

I also have set

```
Prompt=lts
```

in

```
/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

How can I get the upgrade?

Thanks ^^

Comment: For the kernel part, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597341/point-release-upgrade-from-14-04-1-to-14-04-2'

Comment: did you try the classical sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade?
In most cases that will do the trick. What specific distribution do you use ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. More info here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack

Anyone wishing to opt into the hardware enablement stack for Trusty may do so by running following command which will install the linux-generic-lts-vivid and xserver-xorg-lts-vivid packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

If you are on an amd64 system that boots with UEFI, you will also need the matching signed kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic-lts-vivid
```

For anyone interested, the specifics regarding the exact policies and procedures regarding the support, maintenance, and upgrade paths for the hardware enablement stack has been documented at the following location:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 1):

I did some extra googling and found out, that I really have 14.04.3 version already, but the kernel does not upgrade with it automatically. So I did

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

To get the kernel