# ubuntu version shows 14.04.1 but I installed 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I recently checked using the command `uname -a` and this was the output

```
Linux darkheart-Aspire-5610 3.19.0-26-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 12 14:12:35 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Now my question is I installed 14.04.3 lts , then why it shows 14.04.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a correct way to check the version.

`uname -a` gave you the kernel build information and it is correct for 14.04.3.

To see the Ubuntu version run

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought i have to reinstall the whole ubuntu once again just to fix this mess . You saved my time .

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run the following command to know version:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Sample Output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS   
Release:    14.04   
Codename:   trusty
```

You can also use the following command:

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=
```

But your main question is about #28~14.04.**1**  for that please refer [here @Eliah Kagan answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597341/point-release-upgrade-from-14-04-1-to-14-04-2)

Also you may refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion)