# How to "tell" Software updater, I have moved to a new kernel

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, update-manager

I am running ubuntu 14.04 (updated from 12.04 which was preinstalled prior to the release of 14.04.02). I am an experienced non-technical desktop gnu/linux user, but relatively new to ubuntu.
I updated my kernel from 3.13 to 3.16.0-37-generic by executing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

As instructed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).
All went fine. However, Software updater suggests some updates to linux 3.13.0 and apt-get also shows these updates as being held back.
[image]

I do not want to return to 3.13.0, but I do want to receive notifications about updates to the 3.16 series. Do I have to change something in /etc/apt/sources.list, or anywhere else?

Comment: you probably will not receive notifications on new HWE kernels though you can check and install them anytime check my Q: [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618575/how-do-i-find-the-current-stable-kernel-hwe-for-14-04-2) as for the old kernels check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334976/is-it-safe-to-remove-old-kernels-after-installing-the-latest-mainline)