# ubuntu update kernel

Tags: kernel

I thought that the usual update in Ubuntu does install new kernel versions. I noticed that

```
$uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

and

```
$dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic   3.13.0-24.47   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic   3.13.0-27.50   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic   3.13.0-29.53   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic   3.13.0-30.55   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic   3.13.0-34.60   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic   3.13.0-35.62   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic   3.13.0-36.63   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic   3.13.0-37.64   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic   3.13.0-39.66   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic   3.13.0-40.69   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic   3.13.0-43.72   amd64    Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic   3.13.0-44.73   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic   3.13.0-46.79   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic   3.13.0-48.80   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic   3.13.0-49.83   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic   3.13.0-51.84   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.47     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic 3.13.0-27.50     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic 3.13.0-29.53     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic 3.13.0-30.55     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic 3.13.0-34.60     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic 3.13.0-35.62     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic 3.13.0-36.63     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic 3.13.0-37.64     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic 3.13.0-39.66     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic 3.13.0-40.69     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic 3.13.0-43.72     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic 3.13.0-44.73     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic 3.13.0-46.79     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic 3.13.0-48.80     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic 3.13.0-49.83     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic 3.13.0-51.84     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.51.58     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Any idea why the kernel was not updated?

thanks

edit :  I checked the grub configuration and found the following:

```
insmod gzio insmod part_msdos insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4
fi
linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not updated? You have plenty of kernels, including the latest one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [kernel version 3.13 even I have ubuntu 14.04.2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622753/kernel-version-3-13-even-i-have-ubuntu-14-04-2)

Comment: read [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618575/how-do-i-find-the-current-stable-kernel-hwe-for-14-04-2) I hope you'll understand it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have ubunutu 14.02 ( I did not upgrade to a newer version. The second comment concerns upgrade to a newer version). There are newer versions than the 3.13.0.24. But when I update the system I do not pass to the newer kernel.

Comment: Ooops. See `uname -r`? OP probably booted with a previous kernel using grub, or I have no ideas. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: @111 you can also clean old unneeded kernels [check here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: But I have the oldest version.

Comment: @Pilot6. Maybe you are right about the grub. I edit the original post.

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Is it safe? My system is dual boot. Do I have to do this, periodically?

Comment: Yes, it must be safe.

Comment: But it runs on every new kernel image install. The question is why it did not in your case.

Comment: I run sudo update-grub, reboot, but again from uname -r got 3.13.0-24-generic

Comment: I changed manually 0.24 to 0.51 (in grub) and now I have uname -r, 3.13.0-51-generic (the latest kernel)

Answer (score 0):

Linux 3.16 is the latest version of [Linux available in Ubuntu 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image), and Canonical provide long term support for it, rather than giving users the very latest available version. You probably need to update your system to receive it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

`dist-upgrade` differs from `upgrade` in that it updates packages that might otherwise be 'held back', which sometimes includes the kernel. Currently, you are using the latest 3.13 kernel, which will still get security updates, but you'll have to `dist-upgrade` to get 3.16.

On Ubuntu 15.04, however, the [latest version available on Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/linux-image) is 3.19. If you're using Ubuntu 15.04, again, update using the above method.

If you want to use the *very* latest mainline kernels, you can download them from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) - scroll to the bottom to find the latest version. However, you should not do this on a production computer, because these can be more buggy and could break your system.

You will also have to manually update these every time, because there's no automatic update method. (This *used* to be a PPA, but now you have to manually download each version).

Comment: 3.13 is NOT the latest available kernel in 14.04.

Comment: sorry you're right, updating...

Comment: Please read my duplicate comment to the OP. 3.16 and 3.19 are available with updates. You are misleading a bit.

Comment: fixed, please correct me if I've made any more mistakes...

Comment: Please read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/622754/167850)

Comment: afaik, dist-upgrade does just that - upgrades packages that otherwise are held back. So dist-upgrade should install the latest kernel, whereas upgrade will install the latest 3.13.x kernel.

Comment: @DavidBailey `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` will install and use 3.19 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04.2 it's about HWE kernel support. ;)

Comment: you have typo in "Canonical" ;)

Comment: @JoKeR fixed typo

Comment: And 15.04 is always with 3.19, so it is not relevant.